# Display Forms success message in popup after Web Api Success Call

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am working in `Sitecore/SXA 9.3`. I created a form with Sitecore Forms with a custom Submit Action and I'm able to hit Web Api in my C# code with the use of the `SubmitActionBase` base class and return the response/success Message in the page inline.

But I want to show a Success Message in a popup of the page, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in jquery function by binding to ajax:complete event , but in this case , you would need to submit the form aynchronously so that when the response comes back from customsubmitaction class , the popup/success message can be enabled. This would also require checking the `IsAjax` checkbox on the form.

```
 $("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
   //enable modal div for success popup
   });
```